# Does hardware specifications need to be referenced?

Tags: computer-science, ieee

Split between this, when talking about hardware, do you need to reference where you got the information from? For example, "this firewall has xyz ports and is capable of IPSec", would I need to reference where I got this information from?

Comment: Depends what sort of document you are writing.

Comment: Depends whether the information is well known. For instance, saying _the ball is oval_ would be reasonable without reference (in the US, at least).

Comment: Wouldn't you usually write a full sentence about the hardware? E.g. "We used a XyzCorp SuperHackerStopper 9001 firewall (reference to firewall information here) which has 200 ports and supports IPSec at gigabit speeds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Cite Hardware in Scientific Articles?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90145/how-to-cite-hardware-in-scientific-articles)